# H2 SQL syntax error when same query works fine on Postgres

Tags: sql, scala, h2, slick

I have been using slick for DB interaction and h2 in-memory database for testing. So, I just added a new method where I have written plain SQL a query instead of a slick one.

Slick version: 3.3.0 HikariCp: 3.3.0 H2: 1.4.200

So it fails with the plain sql query with the syntax error exception.

```
 def filterTasksByGivenConstraints(taskIds: List[Long], constraints: String): Future[Vector[Int]] = {
          val ids = taskIds.mkString("'", "','", "'")
          
          println(s"SELECT id FROM task where id in ($ids) and $constraints")

          val query = sql"""SELECT "id" FROM "task" WHERE "id" IN (#$ids) and #$constraints""".as[Int]
           db.get.run(query)
              .recover {
                case ex: Exception =>
                  logger.error(s"An exception has occurred while fetching filtered tasks $ids for given constraints $constraints and exception is: $ex")
                  throw ex.getCause
            
        }
      }
```

Query printed in println:

```
SELECT id FROM task where id in ('1') and ("expire_on" <= '2020-07-18') and (("expire_on" at time zone 'EST')::date >= '2020-07-16'::date and ("expire_on" at time zone 'EST')::date <= '2020-07-18'::date) and (("claim_number" = 'foo20') or ("referred_to" = '21'))
```

Exception:

```
15:16:01.063 [scala-execution-context-global-23] ERROR io.inbox.stream.db.DBOperations - {"Level":"ERROR","Message":"An exception has occurred while fetching filtered tasks '1' for given constraints (\"expire_on\" <= '2020-07-18') and ((\"expire_on\" at time zone 'EST')::date >= '2020-07-16'::date and (\"expire_on\" at time zone 'EST')::date <= '2020-07-18'::date) and ((\"claim_number\" = 'foo20') or (\"referred_to\" = '21')) and exception is: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement \"SELECT \"\"id\"\" FROM \"\"task\"\" WHERE \"\"id\"\" IN ('1') AND (\"\"expire_on\"\" <= '2020-07-18') AND ((\"\"expire_on\"\" AT[*] TIME ZONE 'EST')::DATE >= '2020-07-16'::DATE AND (\"\"expire_on\"\" AT TIME ZONE 'EST')::DATE <= '2020-07-18'::DATE) AND ((\"\"claim_number\"\" = 'foo20') OR (\"\"referred_to\"\" = '21')) \"; expected \"(, ., [, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )\"; SQL statement:\nSELECT \"id\" FROM \"task\" WHERE \"id\" IN ('1') and (\"expire_on\" <= '2020-07-18') and ((\"expire_on\" at time zone 'EST')::date >= '2020-07-16'::date and (\"expire_on\" at time zone 'EST')::date <= '2020-07-18'::date) and ((\"claim_number\" = 'foo20') or (\"referred_to\" = '21')) [42001-197]","TimeStamp":"2020-08-13 15:16:01.063","api_app_log":"io.inbox.stream.db.DBOperations"}
```

I even run on Postgres, the printed query is working fine. I am not able to find the issue with h2.

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE` is only supported since H2 1.4.200.

Comment: Another good example on why testing on something different than the production databases doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Thanks for the response. I upgraded version but still same error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I agree with you.

Comment: Please, edit your question and replace the exception message with message from the new version.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I just noticed when i ran test cases after upgrading h2, there is no error but when i run specific test from IDE then it gives error

Comment: `42001-197` error code clearly indicates that it came from H2 1.4.197, you need to check your classpath.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov You can add your suggestion in answer. It is is not giving an error in the terminal so it is correct. There must be some issues that IDE. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zone specifiers `… AT TIME ZONE …` and `… AT LOCAL` are only available since H2 1.4.200.